How do Dispensationalists tell which passages are for Jews and which are for Gentiles?
As I understand it, a key part of dispensationalist theology is a separation between Jews (Israel) and the Church as two separate entities with distinct purposes in God's plan. In discussions with them, I find that they often assert that some passages of the Bible are for Israel while others are for the Church; the process of distinguishing them is sometimes called "rightly dividing the Word of God." However, I often fail to see how they can tell which is which. In a discussion with a dispensationalist pastor I had recently, he seemed to believe that every other paragraph in Galatians is directed at Israel or directed at the Church, and I found myself totally at a loss to be able to follow.
I am wondering, what methodology do Dispensationalists use to determine which passages are directed at which group?

"assert that some passages of the Bible are for Israel while others are for the Church" — it would help if the question included explicit quotations of these assertions from their literature. ¶ "seemed to believe that every other paragraph in Galatians is directed at Israel or directed at the Church" — again explicit examples of which verses were applied to which group would improve the question.

Peter, James, John (the twelve) were followers of Christ's earthly ministry to Israel (the circumcision). Paul was commissioned by Christ ascended in heaven to be the apostle to the Gentiles (the uncircumcision):
Galatians 2:7-9

But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter;
8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:)
9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision.

Romans 11:13

For I speak to you Gentiles, inasmuch as I am the apostle of the Gentiles, I magnify mine office:

Romans 15:8

Now I say that Jesus Christ was a minister of the circumcision for the truth of God, to confirm the promises made unto the fathers:

Romans 15:16

That I should be the minister of Jesus Christ to the Gentiles, ministering the gospel of God, that the offering up of the Gentiles might be acceptable, being sanctified by the Holy Ghost.

Galatians 1:11-12

But I certify you, brethren, that the gospel which was preached of me is not after man.
12 For I neither received it of man, neither was I taught it, but by the revelation of Jesus Christ.

Early in his ministry, Paul went to the unbelievung Jews first in hopes of converting them, but when they would not listen, he was to then turn to the Gentiles:
Acts 13:46

Then Paul and Barnabas waxed bold, and said, It was necessary that the word of God should first have been spoken to you: but seeing ye put it from you, and judge yourselves unworthy of everlasting life, lo, we turn to the Gentiles.

Paul wrote thirteen epistles of the Bible (Romans through Philemon) that are to everyone living today (Eph 3:2) and are identified by his promised salutation, found in the first verse of the first chapter in each:
2 Thessalonians 3:17

The salutation of Paul with mine own hand, which is the token in every epistle: so I write.

Paul, for the most part, if not always (debatable), addresses believers.  The confusion may stem from him often speaking of his unbelieving Jewish "brethren", as it was to Israel that the promises to their fathers (Abraham, Issac, and Jacob) were made.  He desperately wanted them to first recognize the truth in who Christ was (Israel's Messiah), and to then understand all that Christ's atoning blood fulfilled and gifted to humanity:
Romans 10:1-4

Brethren, my heart's desire and prayer to God for Israel is, that they might be saved.
2 For I bear them record that they have a zeal of God, but not according to knowledge.
3 For they being ignorant of God's righteousness, and going about to establish their own righteousness, have not submitted themselves unto the righteousness of God.
4 For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to every one that believeth.

1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

The fact that Paul had converted both Jews and Gentiles through his gospel into the church, the body of Christ, may make reading his epistles a bit confusing, but recognizing the distinction itself does help.
Miles Coverdale, an early translator of the Bible to English and influential in the publication of the King James Version, made the following observation regarding study practices that will assist:

It shall greatly help you to understand Scriptures
If thou mark not only what is spoken or written,
But of whom, and to whom, with what words, at what time.
Where, to what intent, with what circumstances,
Considering what goeth before and what followeth after.

From The Maranatha Bible Society

The Bible is a progressively revealed book. It is the Book of God’s revelation of Himself to mankind … first to mankind in general, then to the chosen nation of Israel, and lastly to “the church, which is His Body.” Because of these various entities we cannot take all of the Bible as TO US. We cannot take what God gave to Israel, as a nation, and make it to us today. What was revealed to one group at one time, cannot necessarily be interpreted to another group at another time. For instance, what the earthly Christ told the disciples to do in the Gospels was not what the risen Christ in glory told Paul to do in his epistles. The message of the twelve was to Israel, and concerned the kingdom of heaven and their Messiah; whereas the message of Paul had nothing to do with Israel, but concerned “the church, which is His Body.”
We know that “all Scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, and for instruction in righteousness,” and that the O.T. Scriptures are written for our example and learning. What we cannot do is take all that is written “for us,” and make it “to us,” who are members of the Body of Christ. To do so is to end up in hopeless confusion. Therefore we ask the questions which Miles Coverdale set forth in his method of study whereby we can discern the interpretation, the application, or the implication.
This is in obedience to the admonition given to us, “Study to show thyself approved unto God, a workman that needeth not to be ashamed, rightly dividing the word of truth” (2 Timothy 2:15).


Does this imply that the non-Pauline epistles are to the Jews and not to the Church? How about the Gospels?

@DarkMalthorp Of course the entire Bible is profitable to all for doctrine, learning, instruction (2 Tim 3:16), but yes. Paul's epistles reveal the hidden "mysteries" kept secret since the world began (Rom 16:25), and directly to the church, the body of Christ. The gospels were directly to Israel regarding the coming kingdom of heaven and 'prophecy' that was revealed to Israel's prophets "since the world began" (Luke 1:70). Had Israel accepted Christ as Messiah, Paul would not be in the picture, but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, "to provoke them to jealousy".

The methodology adopted by many dispensationalists is to place a particular interpretation at the close of Revelation chapter 3, which they claim applies to every following chapter up until the end of chapter 19. This 'allows' them to make a clear divide between the church and the nation of Israel. This interpretation belongs to what is generally called "The Futurist Interpretation" of Revelation. This is briefly explained in this book, which soundly opposes such an interpretation:

"The Futurist Interpretation views the church prophetically from the
day of Pentecost till the second coming of Christ in historical
sequence throughout Chapters 2 and 3 of the book. [But] in chapter 4:1
a secret rapture of the church is proposed, the history of which had
been recorded in the prior chapters.
It follows therefore that the prophetic narrative of events from
chapter 4 to chapter 20 have nothing to do with the church. It is
presumed that this is to do with Israel over a future seven year
period of tribulation.
In chapter 20 the thousand years are taken literally, assuming Israel
on earth, and the church suspended above it in heaven for the entirety
of this period. Old testament priesthood, sacrifices, temple, and
covenant figures are expected to be reinstituted beneath the heavenly
suspension of the church for the duration, the Lord himself being, as
is supposed, on earth reigning over Israel and the world.
This astounding scheme was recovered from oblivion - the Reformation
by then seeming to be of little consequence - largely by the
ecumenical meetings for prophecy at the castle of Lady Powerscourt in
Ireland.  N.J. Darby and other early brethren leaders, many of them
clergymen, featured prominently.
The Plymouth Brethren adopted and propagated this... subterfuge with
great vigour from the 1830's onward. After the division at Plymouth,
the American Scofield incorporated this... with other horrific
schemes, such as dispensationalism, interleaving such things so as to
add them to the Holy Bible, newly dubbed 'The Scofield Bible'." The
Revelation of Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe, pp.14-15, 1998,
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingytrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

This means, then, that this interpretation depends utterly, and vitally, upon teaching a secret rapture of the church from chapter 4 verse 1, for 16 whole chapters, until chapter 20 starts. Thus, for 16 consecutive chapters of Revelation, nothing whatever applies to the church; it all has to be interpreted as applying to fleshly Israel. The rest of New Testament statements about Israel and the Church are interpreted in accordance with that.
The words of Revelation 4:1, "Come up hither" (to heaven, to see what events would follow) were spoken to John with regard to the on-going vision. However, this is interpreted as applying to the entire ecclesia, or assembly of believing Christians. As explained here:

"Moreover they propose that this text suggests the occasion of what
they call 'the secret rapture', as opposed to what they suppose to be
the 'revelation', an artful euphemism for some sort of general
resurrection, which they say is not described until chapter 20.
To fit in with this... they invent the required number of 'second'
comings. However, their 'secret rapture' is so secret that John was
quite ignorant of it, completely failing to mention any such
ridiculous notion." (Ibid. p. 82)

As mentioned earlier, this author has no enthusiasm for this dispensationalist idea. He points out that Revelation 4:1 says John heard the voice of a trumpet 'talking to me', singular. The voice said, 'Come up hither, and I will show thee' - second person singular; to no one else. Nowhere in chapter 4 is there any mention (or hint) of Jesus' second coming. Nor is there mention of any resurrection, or of 'the last trump'. Indeed, J.N. Darby admitted, "There is no mention here of the fact of the Lord's coming in reference to the assembly... Here it is left out." (Ibid. p. 83)

"Having identified the ecclesia, assembly, or church, with the
twenty-four elders seen in heaven in chapter 4:4, therefore Messrs.
Darby and Kelly require us to assume that somewhere between the end of
chapter 3 and the 4th verse of chapter 4, a rapture involving the
Lord's return and the glorified resurrection of the bodies of myriads
of saints, raised from earth to heaven in unapproachable light, was so
secret that John missed it.  ...William Kelly is reported as saying,
"One important thing, then, we have seen to be assumed... This most
solemn and blessed event must occur therefore between chapter 3 and 4
of this book." (Ibid. p. 85)

Dispensationalists would put the case for this idea somewhat differently, I am sure, but as I am not one of them, I have to leave it to them to rectify any errors they see in this answer by providing their own.


thanks for your help in clarifying a very confusing issue.  I hope someone will deal with the matter as applied to the Book of Daniel and other OT works interpreted to apply to the end times.


That's interesting, because what I hear from them is usually that the Church/Israel distinction implies the pretrib rapture, but you are claiming the reverse. Is it circular reasoning, then?

@DarkMalthorp  No, it's not the reverse. Before the future 7 year tribulation breaks out, they expect this 'secret rapture' so that all the dead saint's bodies will be raised, and all living saints will disappear. This is their idea of Jesus' 2nd coming - invisibly. After 7 years, Christ will come again - for a third time, to usher in a millennium when he will rule on Earth. That's how I understand it.
